# Use Repository Pattern in WP theme

Tags: wp-query, oop, repository

In my template files I have a lot of WP_Query to get posts of an author or from a specif category ecc... I'm thinking to use Repository Patter in order to have cleaner code and a layer between database and theme.

This PostRepository class will have some methods like:
- getByID
- getByAuthor
- getByCategory

Could be a good idea? Have somebody use somethink like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes absolutely, It would be great to abstract away your queries at a single place. You might also use caching in your repository.